# Hexadecimal sequence in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sequence

I would like to generate 16 char length hex decimal value as sequence. My database is Oracle and would like to know is it possible to do so? I checked the SEQUENCE in Oracle but I think its only for numericals.

Any idea would be great help.
Thanks in advance,
Abdel Olakara

Comment: Hexadecimal values ARE numbers, by definition. Binary, decimal, hexadecimal are just different ways of representing numbers.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I agree - 0x1 is still 1.  Storing as hexadecimal is a waste of space vs numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Oracle sequences are integers.

In order to use a sequence to generate a 16 character length hexadecimal value, you need to use [TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php):

```
TO_CHAR(your_sequence.NEXTVAL,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

[List of supported `TO_CHAR`/`TO_NUMBER` formats](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp).

Comment: Put the above in a trigger and you should be all set